# Help me ID this bike please

Tags: identify-this-bike

Can anyone help identify this old hottie? Kinda looks like 80's Peugeot per the Shimano 105 parts. The head badge looks like it could have been in the shape of a shield though. Seat tube has a sticker that reads BULLSHOT (grease). I doubt the handlebars and seat are original. Any thoughts? Thanks all!

(Handlebars will be wrapped)

Serial G0583

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You mention the head badge. Could you also post a picture of it? someone might recognize it as well.

Comment: the head badge is missing as well, but there is a faint shape like a shield where there may have been a badge.

Comment: Shield shaped badges are sadly a very common feature.

Comment: ??
1988 Centurion Cavaletto Dark Green/White Fade
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-oEGCE66X9X8/VKZgK-Y3FaI/AAAAAAAAALk/SUNIp3-TdRQ/s1600/IMG_2223.jpg

Comment: ?? 1988 Centurion Ironman Expert Dave Scott - Bright Marine Green/White ??
http://vintage-centurion.com/models/competition/ironman/87-89_expert.shtml

But the colors are still kinda wrong.

Comment: SERIAL CLUE?? 
GIANT (Taiwan):
1978-1986: Gmmyy on rear dropout. (month, month, year, year)
https://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage/1042901-asian-serial-number-guide.html

Comment: Fairly generic 80s bike.  Looks like it's been repainted at least once.

Comment: From the lugs at the drop-outs and the plate behind the BB: It had mudguards and a stand at some time

Comment: It does remind me of my late 80s Centurion.

Comment: 1983 Giant Peleton would be a good Google search point, unfortunately a few variations exists as with all bike. I’d say it’s been resprayed at some point badly looking at all the crazing around the crank area.

Comment: Stamped dropout and kickstand mount suggest lower end frame. At best straight gauge chromoly main tubes. 105 components are a later upgrade as they would not come stock with this level frame

Answer (score 5):

This frame is manufactured by Giant.  The G0583 is a date code from Giant.  The serial number is on the other dropout.

Giant was contracted to make frames for many brand names in 1983.

Comment: I suspect it was sold as a Schwinn just based on how many bikes Giant was making for them at the time. Maybe a Traveler model

Comment: If you can find the SN, you can check against the Schwinn database at vintageschwinn.com